# Claiming space at the bottom of a page

Tags: spacing, header-footer

If I want to adjust the space occupied at the top of a page. I use the command

```
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
```

The effect of which is that - the page contents move upward by the amount set, e.g. `-0.5in`. This results in an unclaimed space at the bottom of the page. How can I claim that unused space? 
My intent in using `\voffset` is to move the contents of the page a bit up so that more of the page gets filled.

Comment: Better is to use `geometry` package for settings page layout.See its documentation.It is part of your LaTeX installation. Also you can find it on-line by gooogling.

Comment: @Sameeresque I believe you are looking for `\enlargethispage` or `\enlargethispage*`.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use the `geometry`package, as `@Zarko` said. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=25mm,
 }
```